# React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component

Tags: reactjs

React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

here is my code :

```
import './App.css';
import { Row, Col, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ListGame from './components/ListGame';
import Konten from './components/Konten';
import NavbarComponents from './components/NavbarComponents';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from 'react-icons/gi';
import { useState } from 'react';
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const [ showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false)
    return (
      <div className='App'>
      <navbar><NavbarComponents /></navbar>
      <header>
        <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={() => setShowNav(!showNav)}/>
      </header>
      <Sidebar show={showNav}/>
      <div className="mt-3">
          <Konten show={showNav}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use useState in class component React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961065/unable-to-use-usestate-in-class-component-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can only use `setState` in functional components using Hooks,

In class components, you should initialize your state like this, above the `render` method :

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    showNav: false
  };
}
```

You can switch the showNav value by doing this :

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
      <navbar><NavbarComponents /></navbar>
      <header>
        <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={() => this.setState({ showNav: !this.state.showNav })} />
      </header>
      <Sidebar show={this.state.showNav}/>
      <div className="mt-3">
          <Konten show={this.state.showNav}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I think it should be like this. ``<GiHamburgerMenu onClick={() => this.setState({showNav: !this.state.showNav })} />``

Comment: oh yes exactly !

Comment: im trying both of your code, but now im facing new error, said : Line 25:22:  'showNav' is not defined  no-undef, what that supposed to be?

Comment: oh you need to change ```<Sidebar show={this.state.showNav}/>``` and ```<Konten show={this.state.showNav}/>```, I updated my answer too