# Invalide hook call, Hooks can only be calle inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, hook

i created a functionnal component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const listFiliere = ({item}) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return(
        <View style={{ height: 30, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'blue' }}>
            <Text>{ item.name }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default listFiliere
```

I called this one inside class component for renderItem of flatlist; and it return error of invlide hook call; Is the class component which called it the cause or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

it could be a few things. the code you posted is not a lot to go on. Take a look at this page. [A few things you can check](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you are calling useState in a class component, please reference this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961065/unable-to-use-usestate-in-class-component-react-js).

Basically, you cannot use the useState hook in a class component. The class component equivalent would be:

```
export class ListFiliere extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View style={{ height: 30, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'blue' }}>
            <Text>{ item.name }</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so my function can't be called inside class component if it use hook?

Comment: No, you can't use hooks inside a class component.